# Does a magic rectangle exist?

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

My definition of a magic rectangle:

> Any $m \times n$ rectangle where $m \ne n$ and all the numbers $1, 2, 3,\dots, mn$ fit into the rectangle. All horizontal lines, vertical lines, and diagonal lines (albeit not the same length) add up to the same number called a *"magic constant"*

Do any magic rectangles exist? If so, what are some examples? Please include dimensions, magic constant, and if possible, the whole rectangle.

**BONUS: How can you determine a rectangle's magic constant from its $m \times n$ dimensions?**

Comment: How are the diagonals defined? And how many are there?

Comment: The diagonals are every possible diagonal line from 1 edge to another. In the case of a 2x3 there'd be 8 (Unless I miscounted)

Comment: @Robb Any other confusions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No such rectangle exists.

Suppose you have a rectangle with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. If every row adds up to some magic value $M$, then the number obtained by adding together *every* cell in the rectangle must be $m \times M$.

Likewise, if every column adds up to $M$, then the value obtained by adding together every cell in the rectangle must also equal $n \times M$.

So, $m \times M = n \times M$. This can only be true if $m = n$, which corresponds to a square.

Comment: Sound so obvious once you've read it, but it wouldn't have crossed my mind immediately. +1 for pointing out the obvious...

Comment: In addition, even if we relax the constraint that `m != n`, there still exists no nontrivial magic square with the "diagonal" rule in the OP.  Consider the top-left corner.  It is both an element of the long diagonal going all the way to the opposite corner, and the sole element of a very short diagonal perpendicular to the other one.  If the sums in both of these diagonals must be equal, then all the other elements of the long diagonal must be 0; but 0 isn't a permitted number in the square.

Comment: @IstvanChung If the requirements were relaxed even further such that only diagonals of length equal to the shorter side length were considered and three different sums are permitted for horizontal, vertical, and diagonals, then it might be possible. If we completely ignore the diagonals, then it certainly is possible for m=2, n=4. And it is simple to show that m+n must be even.

Comment: Istvan Chung, I think that is almost right, but you need to exclude the case where m = n = 1.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer, unless I'm missing something. OP specifies that M is not the magnitude of a single column/row, as he says "all diagonals add up to M but are not the same length." M != length/width. Am I missing something or is the problem just phrased so ambiguously as to leave no chance of understanding?

Comment: @Aerovistae it's not a clear problem; I'm also not sure what the OP meant with that parenthetical. But the fact is, the diagonals don't matter at all. The argument in this answer is sufficient to prove that no magic rectangle exists, based only on the properties of the rows and columns. No matter what happens on the diagonals, this proof still holds.

Comment: It holds so long as OP meant that the magnitude of each row and column is M, otherwise it does not. And that is unclear, because as you said the whole problem is unclear.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Seems pretty clear to me.  All sums (for columns and rows, just to avoid the diagonals boneheadedness for a while) add up to the same number.  That's how magic squares work.  If the OP meant something else, then the question needs more downvotes.

Comment: And FWIW, M=(1+mn)/2m and M=(1+mn)/2n.  (Each number is in exactly one column and one row; in order for each column *and* each row to add up to M, M must be the sum of all elements divided by the number of (columns|rows).)

Comment: @cHao: sum of all elements is mn(1+mn)/2, not (1+mn)/2. But yes, you can arrive at m = n by this means :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oops.   So yeah, it'd end up being n(1+mn)/2 and m(1+mn)/2 for each row/column.

Comment: @DougMcClean I think that's probably the "nontrivial" part.

Comment: @WChargin Indeed.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Sorry guys.

Comment: If you relax the conditions to "$mn$ consecutive integers" (for $mn$ odd) or "$mn$ integers in arithmetic progression", then it might be possible, by choosing a set for which the magic sum is zero.  For example, (1,2,-7,5,-2 / -4,4, 0, -5, 5 / 3,-6, 7, -1, -3) satisfies the row and column constraints.

Comment: @ralphmerridew In your 3x5 example in the row 1, column 4 position, you have a 5.  Do you mean 6?

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer notes, no two finite numbers can get a solution
However, if we get into the transfinite region, we can easily say one side is infinity and the other is infinity*2, we can get a solution. This is because everything contains the same amount of points, as points are infintesimal.
There are infinitely many possible solutions.

Comment: I don't think infinite numbers are meant to be in the scope of this question.